# MapReduce: Map-only or Reduce-only?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

In my problem I have 100TB of data to be processed.  Every file in this dataset is about 1MB, and can belong in up to 3 of the over 10,000 different "groups" we've defined.  Every group of files needs to be processed together, and there can be anywhere from a few to a few hundred files in a group.  Since we have tens of thousands of such groups, we think this is a good candidate for MapReduce.

I see two possible ways to setup this job (perhaps there are more) with something like Hadoop:

1. **Map-only**: We archive the files by group, so the splitting and subsequent mapping is done at the group level.  Since every map job has the entire group, it can do the processing itself, and we have no need for a reduce job.  But I see a couple of problems with this solution.  First, since files can exist in up to 3 groups, archiving by group could result in a tripling of our storage overhead, in addition to Hadoop's replication factor.  Furthermore, archiving the data like this would make it less usable in other applications that work with the files differently.
2. **Reduce-only**: As I understand it, this paradigm implies a simple "identity" mapper and a data-intensive reducer.  In this solution, the files would be stored unordered on disk, and the mapper would receive a set of files to process.  The mapper would then read the file into memory (at least its header info) to determine what groups it belongs to, then emit (group, file) pairs to be reduced.  The reducer would then be responsible for processing the groups.  However, I worry that we may be losing the benefits of data locality, or bog down the network with too much data traffic, by going this route.

Are both methods valid?  If so, which would be preferred?  Specifically, I feel I understand the pros and cons of the Map-only solution fairly well, but not the Reduce-only.  I am not sure how "data local" reduce jobs are, or if it's considered bad practice to do the "heavy-lifting" in the reduce task.

Comment: Same question here, finally which approach did you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to select map-only solution over reduce-only solution for the performance reasons. 
In my understanding passing data via shuffling mechanism is very computationally intensive. It loads both CPU (serialization), Disk (since all data stored on disk at least once) and network - to pass data. 
In my estimations shuffling is a few times more expensive then loading data via non-local HDFS file.  
 
Taking onto account your data size, and considering that during shuffling data will grow (because of serialization overhead) i would also consider Map only solution in order not to get out of disk space.

Comment: Awesome, that definitely answers my question about the cost of offloading the data processing to the reducers.  It sounds like, in general, you want to try to do most of the work in the mappers, correct?

Comment: Exactly. I always prefer perform most work on mappers and minimize data passed to reducers.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods seems valid. I guess the best thing to do is to try both.
However, the "Reduce-only" version seems to me more typical for a Map Reduce job implemented in Hadoop as the framework itself will be responsible for grouping the files.

However, efficiency it is strictly dependent on the computation that has to be performed. What is the computation? More specifically:

1. Can you process a subset of the elements of a group together? If this is the case you can use a combinator a greatly reduce network traffic.
2. Can you think of different organizations for the groups?

Comment: We actually have over 10,000 groups in total, but every file can be in up to 3 groups (i.e. the groups are not a partitioning of the data, there is some overlap).  So in theory we can process all >10,000 groups at once.  The computation being performed in this case is cross-correlation of waveform data, so we could further divide the groups along the diagonal of the correlation matrix.

Comment: The combinator sounds interesting, but I'm not familiar enough with functional programming to see how I could apply it to reduce network traffic.  Could you elaborate on that?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, in Hadoop every mapper is assigned an amount of work which is equal at least to a single file or a chunk of a file following a principle of data locality.
The combiner is a post mapper function which is executed on the <key,value> pairs outputted by the mappers on a given node.
This is kind of a in-place reduce operation that (generally) reduce the amount of data transmitted since it is done in place (in memory) under the assumption that the reduce operation reduce the size of the data.
Look at the example on the wourdcount combiner here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Unfortunately for this application, even if I created partial correlation matrices, I would still need to keep the data around if even one element of the group were missing.  But definitely a good point to keep in mind, thanks.